# How to change style on click just one element of many same elements - Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm getting data from api like this

```
[
  {"id":1, "name":"a"},
  {"id":1, "name":"a"},
  {"id":1, "name":"a"},
  {"id":1, "name":"a"},
]
```

I'm looping this array in html, but i need to add feature on click to change style. I can't add any boolean variable on each object like isChecked, because array is coming from api like this. How can I solve this, is any way to solve this with rxjs, or another way?

Comment: You're free to add whatever you want to the data once it has been returned from the API.

Comment: @Steve Yeah but i'm working in ionic project, and I think to do this can slow the app

Comment: you can do something like this  onClick(){add a check flag in here to handle the check with the api response eg using the id }

Comment: loop through the array, use ngfor on your template, and bind onclick to a method on your component. like (onclick) = "method()" or use the ng-content directive for dynamic styling. check this https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WeakMap` when you cannot add property to objects, I am assuming you are toggling check, the below code should work for you

```
const clickMap=new WeakMap()

itemClicked(item){
 const checked=!clickMap.get(item)
 clickMap.set(item,checked)
}
```

You can base on this value to toggle css class for checked style

```
clickMap.get(item)
```